# Is there a way to unload a video in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

In our iOS PhoneGap app users can either upload a video from their library or record a video. If they upload from their library and then decide they want to record instead the video that they selected from their library comes up first. They have to click done before the video camera is accessible.

Is there a way through PhoneGap to flush that previous video out so it doesn't come up?

PhoneGap 2.1, iOS 6.1.x